# Custom UITableViewCell in static UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've defined a custom `UITableViewCell` that I'm using in my static `UITableView`. I'd like to access the variables I've defined (`myTableViewImageCell`, etc) but doing it from `tableView:willDisplayCell` seems to say something along the lines of "redefinition of cell type.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    [cell.myTableViewLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.myTableViewLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];   


}
```

Comment: Curious - what do you mean by "static UITableView"?

Comment: A UITableView with only static cells.

Comment: OK, what's a "static cell"? To me, cells are cells. I'm wondering what is the difference, in your mind, between a static cell and a non-static cell and how and why they are treated differently.

Comment: @rmaddy:  It is a `UITableView` with the `Content` set to `Static Cells` in a storyboard.  A `UITableViewController` automatically takes care of displaying all of the cells, as configured in the storyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy: See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html and look at the "Loading Table View Cells from a Storyboard" and "The Technique for Static Row Content" sections.  They are pretty nice.  :)

Comment: @lnafziger Oh, that's what I'm missing. Storyboards. Sorry, I don't use Interface Builder or Storyboards for my apps so I didn't know there was the concept of "static cells". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your cells are the same custom class, you can just change the definition of your method to indicate that and get rid of your first line (which is wrong anyway):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(ANMyTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    [cell.myTableViewLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.myTableViewLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];
    [cell.myTableViewLabel setTextColor:[UIColor hex666Color]];      
}
```

Note however, that if you are doing the same thing to **all** of your cells (as you show here), you should do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `willDisplayCell:`.  That way, the code is run only once when the cell is created instead of every time that it is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, I (mistakingly) thought I wasn't supposed to use cellForRowAtIndexPath with static Tableviews.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't thinking about that.  You should be able to add `ANMyTableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` as the first line of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `return cell;` after you finish configuring it.

Comment: @ang Is that not true? Adding a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to my table handler overrode the static cells and they stopped rendering.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the problem is the extraneous ;cell; you have at the end of the second line. change it to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ANMyTableViewCell *cell = (ANMyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    [cell.myTableViewLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.myTableViewLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];
    [cell.myTableViewLabel setTextColor:[UIColor hex666Color]];      
}
```